# will a hair dryer overload my car?

Tags: honda, electrical, odyssey

I've got a 2012 Honda Odyssey. I'm wondering if I can plug in my hair dryer or if it will overload the car. It uses 1500 watts I think...not sure what wattage a car can handle.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: They do make travel hair dryers that plug into the cigarette lighter socket, but these are miserably weak.

Answer (score 3):

Your owner's manual will explain what the inverter plug is rated for in watts.  The hair dryer will also have a label explaining the maximum watts.

I'm pretty sure the answer is "no".  That plug is for laptop chargers and very small electronics that do not draw much current.  A hair dryer (with the heater) is a huge electrical load - even if it is the 1500 watts you think, that represents almost a 13 ampere load @ 120 volts AC.

I doubt the inverter system in your Odyssey is rated for that.

I could be wrong - I suggest checking the owner's manual to be sure.

A quick internet search seems to suggest that each outlet is only rated for a maximum of 120 watts.  Far below what you would need.  The fuses seem to be 10 amps, so at roughly 12V DC that means a maximum of 120 watts before inverting to AC.

Comment: The efficiency of the the inverter is about 87% as a result the 120 watt DC outlet will  supports only a 100 watt inverter. Definitely not possible.

Comment: Also, factory ports like that often have an amp rating either marked on the outlet or specified in the manual.

Comment: Question. What if the hair dryer's heat switch is in the "off" setting?  That should decrease the load substantially and might actually work..

Comment: @elrobis  *Maybe* ... but don't forget the inrush current for the fan motor might result in a load well above 120 watts power.

Comment: @resident_heretic I agree with your efficiency prediction, but I found one source that claims the manual (I have not seen it) specifies 120 watts AC load maximum.  How this is done through a 10 ampere fuse taking into account the inverter losses is beyond me.  One possibility is the running system voltage might be closer to 13 volts DC.  I wonder if the sockets are live with the ignition off?

Comment: Another thought (yes, I'm drifting... reel me in) is that it may not provide 120V AC with a true 60Hz sine.  It may only be a 108V sawtooth steppy simulation or something that a laptop charger and most electronics can handle (ironically converting back to DC anyway) - typical ratings 100-250V acceptable.  I'd love to find an Odyssey and slap a load and a scope on it for the real truth.  Unfortunately, I think that feature is only on the high-end "Limited" editions.

Comment: The max output of the 12V @10 A source would be only able to kick out 104.4 W AC before the fuse blows. The efficiency rating was quoted on an inverter that I use in my own vehicle. The 120 AC voltage is a RMS value or the effective DC equivalent , the peak is much higher . The load type would also effect it as well whether it is a resistive or reactive load.....now I 'm beginning to drift.

Answer (score 0):

For "will a hair dryer overload my car?" yes, an inverter capable of powering this hairdryer is not going to be fitted as standard, but you could purchase one and fit it or have it fitted.

Comment: An expensive proposition - a 1500 watt capable inverter is going to need short 4 AWG cables connected directly to the battery to handle the nearly 150 amps DC load required, assuming an 87% conversion efficiency.

Comment: @SteveRacer The OP did not mention cost... but it is a viable solution if they really want to power a hairdryer... also size of battery is a concern.